# Is there any easy way to use Hoptoad with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, hoptoad

I know that Hoptoad has a module for PHP at https://github.com/rich/php-hoptoad-notifier/blob/master/Services/Hoptoad.php. I'm trying to figure out how to integrate this into Cake? Will it work right if I run the installer for it in the CakePHP boot? Are there any conflicts between this and CakePHP's functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it as 3rd party extensions under `/app/vendors`, Its easy to configure and run. read how to load [**vendors files**](http://book.cakephp.org/view/538/Loading-Vendor-Files)